# Prove that the equality below

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This question is one of the old exam questions. I could not solve it. Can anyone help me solve this question ? Thank you for your help.
$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N} $ is bounded, smooth domain, $N \geq 1, \lambda(x)$ positive function in $C^2(\Omega)$ and $u$ is a $C^2$ solution of the problem 
       \begin{align}
\Delta u&=\lambda(x)u, \qquad x \in \Omega \\
u&=1, \text{on} \quad \partial\Omega
      \end{align}
Prove that 
\begin{align}
r^{N-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r^{1-N}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} udS\right)=\int_{B(x,r)} \Delta u(y)dy \qquad \forall B(x,r) \subset \Omega
\end{align}